# get working working days from calendar Table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

One is list of holidays school wise of January Month 2010 and other is calendar Table.

I want to calculate data of working days of all three schools in Jan 2010.

I took a just small example from real problem.

Holidays Table

```
SchoolID   HolidayOn    
1          01-01-2010        
1          02-01-2010    
2          01-01-2010   
2          02-01-2010   
3          01-01-2010   
3          02-01-2010     
3          03-01-2010
```

I want working days of All three schools

Output should be like this

```
SchoolID    WorkingDays
1           03-01-2010
1           04-01-2010
1           05-01-2010
1           06-01-2010
.
.
.
.
1           31-01-2010
2           03-01-2010
2           04-01-2010
2           05-01-2010
2           06-01-2010
.
.
.
2           31-01-2010
3           04-01-2010
3           05-01-2010
3           06-01-2010
3           07-01-2010
.
.
.
.
3           31-01-2010
```

I have tried something like this

```
  SELECT C.CalendarDate, H.HolidayOn
         FROM Calendar as C LEFT OUTER JOIN Holidays as H
    ON C.CalendarDate = H.HolidayOn
 WHERE H.HolidayOn IS NULL 
 AND YEAR(C.CalendarDate) IN (2011)
 ORDER BY C.CalendarDate
```

How can I perform these on year basis as well ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Calendar Table Felix

Comment: Added now Craig, please check now

Answer (score 0):

First, get all distinct `SchoolID`s from the `Holidays` table. Then do a `CROSS JOIN` on `Calendar` table to generate all combination of school and calendar dates. And then use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out holidays.

```
SELECT
    s.SchoolID,
    c.CalendarDate
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT SchoolID FROM Holidays
)s
CROSS JOIN Calendar c
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Holidays h
        WHERE
            h.SchoolID = s.SchooldID
            AND h.HolidayOn = c.CalendarDate
    )
    AND c.CalendarDate >= '20110101'
    AND c.CalendarDate < '20120101'
```

Avoid using `YEAR(CalendarDate)` as it prevents your query from using an index. Instead use  `>=` and `<`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all dates for all schools, it's a simple matter of:

```
SELECT  d.SchoolId, d.CalendarDate
FROM    AllDatesAllSchools d
EXCEPT
SELECT  h.SchoolId, h.HolidayOn
FROM    HolidayDates
```

However, you only have all dates; not all dates for all schools. So you first produce that by doing a cross-join over Calendar and AllSchools as a CTE:

```
;WITH AllSchools AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT SchoolId
  FROM    Holidays
), AllDatesAllSchools AS (
  SELECT  h.SchoolId, d.CalendarDate
  FROM    Holidays h
          CROSS JOIN Calendar d
)
SELECT  d.SchoolId, d.CalendarDate
FROM    AllDatesAllSchools d
WHERE   d.CalendarDate >= '20110101'
    AND d.CalendarDate < '20120101'
EXCEPT
SELECT  h.SchoolId, h.HolidayOn
FROM    Holidays h
```

NB: Please note the way I've filtered CalendarDate for a specific year is very deliberate. Using `YEAR(d.CalendarDate)` as you have makes the query non-SARGable, and unable to leverage indexes for performance.